# not receiving the mail but is displayed in terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have followed the tutorial http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html and the mail is displayed in the terminal and it is not displayed in mail.

Comment: Can you tell what command you are typing for mail.

Comment: no i mean what command you are using for sending mail. have u run that in console and tested?

Comment: I am writing answer just check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have made mailer class `Mail` using action mailer as declared below

```
class Mail < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "notifications@example.com"

  def welcome_email() 
    @url  = "http://example.com/login"
    mail(:to => "email@email.com", :subject => "Welcome to My Awesome Site")
  end
end
```

For sending mail you can use

```
Mail.welcome_email().deliver
```

This command will send mail using action mailer.

For testing whether above statement works fine, open rails console using rails c, and type the above command. You will get object to whom and with what subject mail is send.

Comment: I have already done these things but i am not receiving the mail to the specified mail in 'to' field

Comment: check your spam, hav you checked that

Comment: I have checked but not coming

Answer (score 0):

Set `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true` in config/environments/development.rb.

Comment: No still i did not receive the mail.